# How to identify a random process as a measure probability on the space of functions?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a measure space and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) )$. Let $X_t = [X_t: t \in \mathbb{Z}]$ - $X_t: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$,  $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z}$ -  be a random process:
\begin{align}
X : \Omega \times \mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{R}\\
(\omega,t) &\mapsto X_t(\omega)
\end{align}

I am trying to identify the random process $X_t$ with a corresponding measure probability $P_X$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}, \mathcal{B} )$, where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel a-field on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. I will describe my attempt.

First, $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ can be identified as the spaces of functions $x: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\pi_t = [ \pi_t : t \in \mathbb{Z} ]$ - $\pi_t: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}\to  \mathbb{R}$, $\pi_t(x) := x(t)$ - be a random process. That is:
\begin{align}
\pi_t: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} &\to  \mathbb{R}\\
(x,t) &\to x(t)
\end{align}

1. $\,\,X_t$ induces a system of finite-dimensional distributions(fi-di) on $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^k)$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. I will denote this system as $X\#\mathbb{P}$;
2. $\,$ By Kolmogorov existence and uniqueness theorem, given any random process $X_t$ and its fi-di $X\#\mathbb{P}$ on $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^k)$, there is an unique $P_X$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}, \mathcal{B} )$ such that the fi-di of $\pi_t$, denoted as $\pi \#P_X$ , on $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^k)$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, is the same as $X\#\mathbb{P}$.

I would like to know if the $X_t \sim P_X$. Is correct this identification?

Is $P_X$ the correct definition of the distribution of the stochastic process $X_t$?

This question was done in other forum:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553288/how-to-identify-a-random-process-as-a-measure-probability-on-the-space-of-functi